# String Comparison Not Working With Swift

Tags: ios, swift, realm, string-comparison, didselectrowatindexpath

I can't seem to figure out what's going on here. I'm trying to perform an action based on if two strings are a match. Sometimes it seems to work and sometimes it doesn't. My app (written in Swift) allows a user to search through a list of golf courses and select one. If they select one then it is added to Realm as a previous course. If they have already selected this golf course in the past then I'm displaying a message to say they have already selected that course in the past so it isn't added to the list twice. I've tried to remove the white spaces to help but it still doesn't seem to work. Some of the golf courses have characters such as "??, -, $" because of the data base I downloaded it from. Not sure if this matters or not. Again, sometimes it works and sometimes it doesn't. Just not sure why. Thanks.

The two strings I'm comparing in the code are:

```
 if previousCourse.name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") == courseFromRealm.name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "")
```

Full method:

```
    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if searchController.active {

    let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
        let addPreviousCourse = PreviousCourse()

        addPreviousCourse.name = searchResults![indexPath.row].name
        addPreviousCourse.city = searchResults![indexPath.row].city
        addPreviousCourse.state = searchResults![indexPath.row].state

        self.previousCourse = addPreviousCourse

            for course in previousCoursesFromRealm {

                courseFromRealm = course

            }

        if previousCourse.name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") == courseFromRealm.name.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString(" ", withString: "") {

        displayAlert("Whoops!", message: "Check your list of previously selected courses or choose a different course.", actionTitle: "OK")

        } else {

            realm.add(previousCourse)
            print(previousCourse.name)
            searchController.active = false

        }

            if searchController.active == false {

            coursesTableView.reloadData()

           }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Try to log `previousCourse.name` and `courseFromRealm.name`. And also, you don't need to remove white space when doing search function.

Comment: @setonugroho I did print them out and they both printed the same string. That's why I was confused. I thought that maybe the white space was throwing something off so that's why I put that in. Either way it still only sometimes works.

Comment: So what happen you print `previousCourse.name` and `courseFromRealm.name`? Can you edit the question to include the output?

Comment: It could be that the comparison is working, but your `displayAlert` function isn't working properly - try printing something to the console when that function is called

Comment: I know that you are using code to convert the previousCourse.name and courseFromRealm.name to strings, but are you absolutely sure that they are Strings? Also, are you sure that you have removed all white space and made every character lower case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I figured out what was happening. I appreciate everyone's help and the suggestions lead me down a path of trying some other options. What was happening is "courseFromRealm" was only taking on the last value in my previousCoursesFromRealm when using the for-in loop. This is why sometimes it worked and sometimes it didn't because if the course I selected was the last value in the for-in loop then my code appeared to work otherwise it didn't. So I got rid of the for-in loop and used the "contains" method on previousCoursesFromRealm to simply check if this course I was selecting was already in my list of previous courses. If it is then I display the alert message and if not then I add it to the list. Again, thanks for everyone's help! still a little new to programming and working though it.

```
    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {

    tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)

    if searchController.active {

        let realm = try! Realm()
        try! realm.write {
        let addPreviousCourse = PreviousCourse()

         addPreviousCourse.name = searchResults![indexPath.row].name
         addPreviousCourse.city = searchResults![indexPath.row].city
         addPreviousCourse.state = searchResults![indexPath.row].state

         self.previousCourse = addPreviousCourse

            if previousCoursesFromRealm.contains( { $0.name == previousCourse.name }) {

            displayAlert("Whoops!", message: "This course already exists inside of your previous course list. Please choose a different course.", actionTitle: "OK")

            } else {

              realm.add(previousCourse)
              searchController.active = false

                }
            }

            if searchController.active == false {

                coursesTableView.reloadData()

            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use isEqualToString function for comparing two strings.

Comment: In Swift it is ok to use `==` to check for equality, since only `===` checks for identity.